# I answer a question, and then the OP deletes the question. Grrr

Tags: discussion

I saw a question about an hour ago, it looked reasonable. It was about passing an array of values to a function. I answered it, it took 10 or 15 minutes, including making up some example code.

Half an hour later I go to check on whether I made any typos, but couldn't find any history of the question at all! Not even in the "moderator tools" list of deleted questions (ie. "recently deleted").

---

It wasn't listed in my "all actions":

[image: Recent actions]

---

I was starting to doubt my sanity at this point. I'm sure I answered it! I even have the code in my IDE:

```C++
class myClass {
  const int num_;
  const int * values_;

  public:

  // constructor
  myClass (const int num, const int * values) : num_ (num), values_ (values) { } 

  // other stuff here

  // demo
  void printThem ();
};  // end of class myClass

void myClass::printThem ()
  {
  for (int i = 0; i < num_; i++)
    Serial.println (values_ [i]);  
  } // end of myClass::printThem

const int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = 6;
const int myValues [NUMBER_OF_VALUES] = { 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77 };

// make an instance of the class with the wanted values
myClass foo (NUMBER_OF_VALUES, myValues);

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  foo.printThem ();
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {

  }  // end of loop
```

---

So, did I dream it? Did I answer a question that came to me in a vision?

I couldn't find any trace of it, until I remembered the browser history:

[image: Question in my browser history]

There it was! The question **did** exist. Clicking on that link in the browser history revealed the question:

[image: Question, now deleted]

---

And my answer:

[image: Answer to question]

Now I'm pretty pissed off. I've seen this sort of behaviour before on other sites, but I thought StackExchange was supposed to be a knowledge base of good questions and good answers. Not to get an answer and then delete the question **and** the answer.

---

So what's my question?

- Is this acceptable behaviour?
- How do you deal with people that ask a question, wait for you to answer it, and then delete the question?
- Why is the answer not listed in "all actions"? I did an action. I answered a question. I expect that to be listed.
- How can they even **delete the answer** as well? On the Arduino forum, if you delete your question the answer still stays there, and then a moderator tells the person not to do that again.

---

Moderators: Please undelete the question, undelete the answer, protect the question from further deletion, and have a word with the OP.

Comment: Another example of OPs vandalising their own questions, [nRF24L01+ Arduino mpu6050 [closed]](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10583/nrf24l01-arduino-mpu6050)

Comment: I recently had this happen to me after I had spent a good bit of time trying to write a quality answer that should have been helpful to other users with the same question in the future: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/43345. After finding that my answer solved their problem, the author deleted the question. This is the sort of behavior I have come to expect from the average Arduino beginner but the sad thing is that the user who did this is rated in the "top 2%" of Arduino Stack Exchange users.

Comment: I have undeleted that question. I can't see a valid reason for deleting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this acceptable behaviour?

Yes and no. If there was a reason for deletion, it may be OK. However, there doesn't seem to be any reason the OP would delete. Otherwise, I'd say no. It's really dependent on the situation.

> How do you deal with people that ask a question, wait for you to answer it, and then delete the question?

Flag it for moderator attention.

> Why is the answer not listed in "all actions"? I did an action. I answered a question. I expect that to be listed.

Deleted posts aren't listed in that section.

> How can they even delete the answer as well? On the Arduino forum, if you delete your question the answer still stays there, and then a moderator tells the person not to do that again.

We're not the Arduino forum, so there's that.

The OP can delete a question if it has only one answer with no upvotes (in this case they could delete)

---

For now, I've undeleted the question/answer and left a comment to ensure that there isn't some lingering reason the OP wants the question deleted.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the fact that I had to hunt down the link in my browser history shows it would be easy to "get away with" asking a question, getting a good answer, and then deleting both the question and the answer. The rule that he can delete a question if it has only one answer with no upvotes lets him get away with this concept of treating StackExchange as a method of getting free, private consulting. I suggest there should be a time interval before he can do this - so other people can at least view the question/answer and perhaps upvote the answer.